Enabling Preview Feature in Visual Studio Code with Java 17
I have a java 17 Spring Boot project requiring preview features but I can't get it configured correctly.
In VSC, I have configured my project's

JDK Runtime to use JavaSE-17

Compiler to use

the '--release' option for cross-compilation

the Bytecode version: to 17

Here, I have no possibility to enable preview features




In my build.gradle file, I have the following:
// [N]:preview-features - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:feature_preview
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.compilerArgs += '--enable-preview'
}
tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
    jvmArgs += '--enable-preview'
}
tasks.withType(JavaExec).configureEach {
    jvmArgs += '--enable-preview'
}

Such a setting doesn't enable me to use preview features of java 22 in my java editor. But, I can compile, test and run my code with Gradle successfully.
Also, I have a problem when I try to use the Spring Boot Dashboard integrated in VSC. If I try to run or debug my project, I get the following in the output window:
> Build starts at 2024-08-14 07:44:34
Task :compileJava started
Task :compileJava failed
------

Could not execute build using connection to Gradle installation '/Users/utilisationnormale/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current'.
error: invalid source release 17 with --enable-preview
  (preview language features are only supported for release 22)
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

My Gradle version is 8.9
My VSC version is 1.92.0
My Extension Pack for Java is v0.29.0
My Spring Boot Dashboard for VS Code is v0.14.0
Thanks in advance


Under the hood, instead of javac, vscode-java uses ECJ, a Java 22 compiler provided by Eclipse JDT. It is used to compile against all other versions of Java. But the ECJ compiler only supports the latest JDK release when it comes to preview features. It means that, with the latest vscode-java release, preview features can not be enabled for projects compiling against Java 21 (or older), even if you configured the proper runtime. Those projects need to be updated to use Java 22 in vscode-java.

https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Enabling-Java-preview-features
